# auto type defaults to int instead of long

Tags: c++, c, auto, lexical-analysis

I've run into the following example where the **auto declaration defaults to int** instead of long:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto i = 999999999999999;
    // long i = 999999999999999;
    printf("i = %ld\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code, gcc indeed gives a relevant warning that `i` is actually an `int`:

```
$ gcc -o main main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:10: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘i’ [-Wimplicit-int]
     auto i = 999999999999999;
          ^
main.c:4:14: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
     auto i = 999999999999999;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:6:19: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("i = %ld\n",i);
                 ~~^
                 %d
```

But I'm wondering **why gcc's lexical scanner didn't label `999999999999999` as being long** when it has all the information to do so? Here is the output of the program:

```
$ ./main
i = 2764472319
```

**EDIT**:

Here is the output of the correct answer (from @Yang) with g++:

```
$ g++ -o main main.c
$ ./main
i = 999999999999999
```

And another option for doing it:

```
$ cp main.c main.cpp
$ gcc -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp
$ ./main
i = 999999999999999
```

Comment: Note: when or if you compile this as C++ code, the format specification in the `printf` is non-portable, because the type chosen then depends on the number ranges of the built-in types for that compiler.

Comment: Compile with `-pedantic-errors` if you don't want non-standard C such as `auto i` to compile. Implicit int was removed from the language 20 years ago. Also, you should not use `auto` in any flavour of these languages. In C++ after 2011 this keyword creates a massive type-safety hazard, creating subtle but severe bugs. Just never use the keyword in C or C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want type inference, [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) is a C++ feature. Could you try compiling with g++ instead?

In C and C++98/C++03, auto is a redundant keyword meaning "[automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)." So in your example, `i` is a variable with no explicit type which is therefore treated as an `int` (but C99 and later requires a diagnostic).